# How to add numbers between two string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

Sometimes we need to calculate very long number which couldn't hold any numerical data type of C. As we know all common numerical data type has limitation.

I'm beginner and I think... it is possible by string. My question is:

How can I add two strings?

**Sample Input:**

String 1: 1234
String 2: 1234

**Output**
Result : 2468

**[Note: Numbers can be very very long in Strings. Unlimited]**

Comment: Parse the string variables to integer variables. Calculate sum of them, then parse the result to string.

Comment: Can you please type the code?

Comment: Just wrote the code and posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do *not* convert to a number. Instead, add as you (must) have learned in basic eductation: one pair of digits at a time, starting from the lowest (rightmost) and remember to carry the tens forwards (to the left).

The length of the source strings does not matter, but you must be sure the result char array is large enough for the longest input value *plus* one (optional) digit.

The algorithm is so simple that I will *not* "type the code" (which is off-topic for Stack Overflow). It boils down to

```
carryOver = 0

loop:
result0 = inputA0 + inputB0 + carryOver
if result0 > '9'
    carryOver = 1
    result0 -= 10
else
    carryOver = 0
go to loop while there is still input left ...
```

where the `0` in the variable names indicate the index of the current digits under consideration.

Comment: Programming language : C
Actually, I need to know... how to add any long number between two strings.

If Enter is pressed, then the string1 will stop taking input. Will ask for input in string2. After inputting numbers in string2, when again ENTER in pressed then it will show the addition result between two strings.

Comment: Actually I gave you the algorithm above. What part is unclear?

Comment: As I'm beginner, I've problem in implementation.

Comment: But, I got the logic as you nicely explained.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit This Answer does not allow carry overs but infinity long add operations. It does not solve the problem of the user. But it is an implementation example and the user asked for one. This is why I will let the answer stay here and not delete it.**

You can use atoi (ascii to int)

Do you realy mean C or C++?

This code can't calculate 8+3 = 11 but 5+3 = 8. There is no carry over.

```
int temp;
const inst size_of_array;
char one[size_of_array];
char two[size_of_array];
char result[size_of_array];
for(int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++)
{
    temp = atoi(one[i]) +atoi(two[i]);
    results[i] = numberToCharacter(temp);
}

char numberToCharacter((int temp)
{
 if(temp == 1)
 {
  return('1'):
 } ///..
}
```

Comment: This does not fulfil the requirement for a number that "couldn't hold any numerical data type of C", as it is limited to MAX_INT.

Comment: no it can hold 10^Bytes Digits. That is quite alot, in with 1 MB there are 10^1000000 numbers.

Comment: Fair enough, as my comment above was before your change. This is *a* way to do it, but only as a (very rough) starting point.

Answer (score -3):

Parse the string variables to integer variables. Calculate sum of them, then parse the result to string.

**[Here is a fiddler.](http://ideone.com/385zsc)**

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    //Declaring string variables
    char string1[10] = "1234";
    char string2[10] = "1234";
    //Converting them to integer
    int int1 = atoi(string1);
    int int2 = atoi(string2);
    //Summing them
    int intResult = int1 + int2;
    //Printing the result
    printf("%d", intResult);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not fulfil the requirement for a number that "couldn't hold any numerical data type of C", as it is limited to MAX_INT.